# Django Models Option Save

Tags: django, class, models

i just want to ask how it works that method "save", in this model?
I just trying to add this to my code, but i really dont know how it works..
Those lines help me to save the slugify if theres is not an id in the model?
Thank you so much.

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: this helps you to add slug into new object.

To check if object is new you perform this validation:

```
if not self.id:
```

this return True only if `self.id` is empty. Considering `id` is primary key it is only possible for new object.

```
self.slug = slugify(self.name)
```

Now you convert `name` field into slug using [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) util:

> Converts to ASCII if allow_unicode is False (default). Converts spaces to hyphens. Removes characters that aren’t alphanumerics, underscores, or hyphens. Converts to lowercase. Also strips leading and trailing whitespace.
>
> For example:
>
> slugify(value)
>
> If value is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "joel-is-a-slug".

And finally you call

```
super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

to save object.

Comment: best explanation ever thank you so much @neverwalkaloner

Comment: so is a good practice to do this on the models right? @neverwalkaloner

Comment: @soultaker you are very welcome! Yes, this is common practice.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will ask you something else if I go down again with my code or I struggle with something, I'm new on this. @neverwalkaloner